# Is Possible to Configure SSO from Citrix to Salesforce

Tags: single-sign-on

1. I have the users working in the citrix environment (Virtual system). When the users logged in to the citrix system by using there login.
2. salesforce should not ask for the username and password to login-in to production.

I am trying to setup the SSO. As users have to remember so many passwords.

Does anyone know if it is possible to set up SSO-integration with citrix systems?

Comment: Assuming it's a normal Windows environment, have you looked into using ADFS to SSO to salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under ADFS you should be able to set up your SSO. There are a number of very important parts needed to be correctly set SFDC's SSO. Issuer, Identify Provider Certificate, Identity Provider Login Url (this one should point to your adfs/ls), OAuth 2.0 Token Endpoint. The algorithm needs to be SHA-1 or SHA-256. So if Citrix supports and can generate those parameters you should be able to set up SSO with that system. 
I will recommend you to start looking to articles like this one: 
[SSO from SFDC to Citrix GoToMeeting/GotToWebinar/GotoTraining](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Configuring-SAML-SSO-to-Citrix)